# Why assignments don't return undefined?

Tags: typescript

As you may know, JavaScript returns `undefined` for assignments, e.g. `var a = 0;`. However, TypeScript is not consistent with that fact, and seems to return the assigned value (`0`) – yet I could not find any information about this online.

As an example, see this code snippet.

```js
function f(): void {
 let l: number = 1;
 return (l = 2); // f() returns 2
}

alert(f());
```

I would like to learn the reasons behind this decision, and to hear opinions about it.

Comment: What is run is the right side, which is JavaScript.

Comment: `var a = 0` evaluates to undefined, but that's not what is returned. What is returned is the expression `(l = 2)`, which evaluates to 2, in TypeScript and in JavaScript, as TypeScript is compiled to the identical expression in JavaScript

Comment: Don't even run it. TypeScript complains before that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code snippet contains `return (l = 2)`, *an assignment*, not `return (var l = 2)` (which is of course not valid code), the former will return `2` in JavaScript, TypeScript, or indeed C or Java.

A *variable declaration* `var l = 2` is a statement, however only expressions have values.

Comment: You are right. However, the latter is not valid code. Is there any way of effectively capturing the value of the declaration? Although to this point, I suppose it does not really matter; TypeScript is behaving as it should, only not as I thought things worked – it is not true that assignments return undefined, but declarations do.

Comment: Just trying in the console... captured will hold the value `2` after that, not `undefined` (the value returned by the declaration). Anyway, this is just for the shake of curiosity (it doesn't have to be pretty), but pointless after all.

Comment: Sorry what did you mean by "`value of the declaration`" then?

Comment: If you just type in the console `var a;`, you will see that the value returned is `undefined`, without any actual assignment.

Comment: Oh, I guess that's more of an artefact of the console, there is no value so it prints undefined, it might as well not have printed anything. A variable declaration is a statement, not an expression (also why `return var l = 2` is not valid)